# Set Network Proxy Linux

Tags: linux, proxy, raspberry-pi

I have a *raspberry pi* and I need to set a network proxy for both `apt` and browser.

How do I do this?

The only thing I have found is to use the following lines in the `bash.bashrc` file

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```

However I do not have a `username` or `password` as the proxy does not require authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your `.bashrc`:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxyhost:port

export ftp_proxy=http://proxyhost:port
```

If you don't neeed authentication just don't add it.

Comment: Ok, I have now added the lines http_proxy=***.**.***.**:**** and ftp_proxy=***.**.***.**:**** to the bottom of my bash.bashrc file (obviously with real ips rather than asterix) But I still have no access to the net..... do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Did you logged out and logged in again so the `.bashrc` gets sourced?

Comment: I restarted the pi and it loaded up fine. However the bash.bashrc file is now blank!

Comment: Ok, I forgot to include the export command at the beginning of each line. 

I now have access to the internet via a browser. However I still can't get access via apt

I have tried adding a 01proxy file under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ and adding the line

Acquire::http:proxy "http://111.111.111.111:1111"; but this file saves ok (I can re-open it and the information is there) but when I restart the pi I still have no apt web access and the 01proxy file is now empty again!

Comment: Ok if I use sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::proxy http://111.111.11.11:8080 update, it works fine, so it is obviously just a matter now of knowing where to set the proxy

Comment: Nice, good work! :-)

Comment: I have changed the 01proxy file to read Acquire::http::proxy 111.111.11.11:8080 but this now results in an error when I call sudo apt-get update which says extra junk at end of file.....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Raspian, create a file called 99proxy containing

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://111.111.11.11:8080";
```

in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/

If your distribution does not use apt.conf.d/, put the same line in /etc/apt/apt.conf